# En esta oración compleja ¿cuáles son las oraciones subordinadas y qué función desempeñan?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

Oración compleja:

> ha sido en la última década cuando la importación de vocablos de ese idioma ha  crecido, sobre todo entre los jóvenes.

Estoy un poco inseguro de cuáles son las oraciones subordinadas (y cual es la oración principal) y qué función desempeñan las subordinadas.

He llegado a esto:

- ha sido en la última década ***Or. principal***

  - cuando la importación de vocablos de ese idioma ha crecido EDIT: ***Subord. adjetiva (antecedente=década)***

    - sobre todo entre los jóvenes EDIT: ***topicalizador / elemento periférico***

Estoy muy inseguro. Cualquier ayuda es muy apreciada.

Comment: Una pregunta, a raíz de la muy buena respuesta de @Fran: ¿cuál es el sujeto de tu oración?. En mi respuesta me basé en que este sujeto estaba tácito, considerando a "la importación de vocablos de ese idioma" como un complemento temporal de la frase.

Answer (score 2):

Yo identifico otras estructuras:

- Sujeto:

  - Tácito, reemplazable por "ello", "aquel fenómeno", "esa tendencia".
- Predicado:

  > ha sido

  - Complemento circunstancial de tiempo, con una *oración subordinada circunstancial de tiempo*:

    > en la última década, cuando la importación de vocablos de ese idioma ha crecido
  - Complemento circunstancial ¿de compañía?:

    > sobre todo entre los jóvenes.

    - Sobre este complemento, no estoy por ahora totalmente seguro.

Acerca del verbo, corresponde a una acepción de *ser* que es usado con un significado de *ocurrir*, *darse*, *producirse*, el que por ser *intransitivo* carece de *complemento directo*.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con esta respuesta. Sin embargo, quisiera opinar sobre la frase `sobre todo entre los jóvenes`. No creo que es CC de compañía. Yo la analizo como un CC de modo (por la locución adverbial `sobre todo`), que precede un complemento de régimen preposicional distributivo, `entre los jóvenes`.

Answer (score 1):

Tengo muy olvidado analizar gramaticalmente una oración, pero conceptualmente, si tuviera que decir lo mismo de una forma más directa, yo pondría:

> La importación de vocablos de ese idioma ha crecido en la última década, sobre todo entre los jóvenes.

O resumido como una lista numerada:

> La importación de vocablos de ese idioma ha crecido:
>
> 1. en la última década
> 2. sobre todo entre los jóvenes.

Que en realidad no es más que dos oraciones con mismo el sujeto (la importación ...) y verbo (ha sido) pero diferente predicado:

> La importación de vocablos de ese idioma ha crecido en la última
>   década.
>
> La importación de vocablos de ese idioma ha crecido sobre todo entre
>   los jóvenes.

El predicado principal es que ocurre (1) de forma general y dentro de este ocurre (2) de forma particular.  Además, se pone especial énfasis en (1) al recurrir al recurso de comenzar con la forma pasiva "Ha sido (1) cuando ..."

Lo que, en resumen, supongo que equivale a decir que (2) es un complemento.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, pero no estoy seguro de que "La importación de vocablos de ese idioma" sea el sujeto original de la frase. Le acabo de preguntar al OP acerca de ello.

Comment: Nicolás, como decía el análisis gramatical lo tengo olvidado, pero un truco para averiguar muchos sujetos es preguntar ¿quién? aunque no vale para todos los casos. ¿Quién ha crecido? La importación ...  ¿Y quién "ha sido"? Pues aquí no está tan claro, pero más que un sujeto tácito yo dría que es "cuando  crece la importación..." Al menos dándole la vuelta a la frase parece un sujeto+verbo+predicado con sentido semántico: {Cuando la importación ... ha crecido}{ha sido}{en la última década}.

Comment: ¿Cómo es posible que nadie haya notado en todo este tiempo que ésta es la respuesta correcta?